# Iteration starting at the wrong point (List index out of Range)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am working on code that uses loops (currently for loop), utilizing Heron's method, to find an estimate of the square root, while also displaying the iteration and relative change.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# Problem 1.

def square_root_for(a, x0, max_iter = 10, tol=1e-14):  
    
    """ (number, integer, number) -> float

    Return an estimate of the square root of a number using the Heron's method.
        
    >>> square_root_for(5, 5)
    Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change
    -------------------------------------------------
    1         | 3.00000000000000 | 0.4000000000000000
    2         | 2.33333333333333 | 0.2222222222222222
    3         | 2.23809523809524 | 0.0408163265306123
    4         | 2.23606889564336 | 0.0009053870529653
    5         | 2.23606797749998 | 0.0000004106060359
    6         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000842
    7         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000000
    2.23606797749979
    """
    
    x = [x0]
    x.append(a/x0)
  
    print('Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change')
    print('-------------------------------------------------')
         
    
    for i in list(range(1,( max_iter + 1),1)):
       #x[i+1] = (s1 + x[i]) / 2
      
        change = (abs(x[i] - x[i-1]) / x[i-1])
        if change > tol:
            x.append(1/2 * (x[i] + (a / x[i])))
        print('{}         | {:.14f} | {:.16f}'.format(i, x[i], change))
        i = i + 1
    
           
# Don't change or delete the 5 lines of code below.
a = 5
max_iter = 100
tol = 1e-15
x_final = square_root_for(a, a, max_iter, tol)
print('Final estimate using square_root_for is {0}'.format(x_final))
```

It mostly works, but my example displays as:

```
Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change
-------------------------------------------------
1         | 1.00000000000000 | 0.8000000000000000
2         | 3.00000000000000 | 2.0000000000000000
3         | 2.33333333333333 | 0.2222222222222222
4         | 2.23809523809524 | 0.0408163265306123
5         | 2.23606889564336 | 0.0009053870529653
6         | 2.23606797749998 | 0.0000004106060359
7         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000842
8         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000000
```

This is incorrect. The first row's estimate and relative change should not be there, and instead it should be the second row's estimate and relative change corresponding to Iteration 1. There should also only be 7 iterations, but because of this problem there are 8.

The code returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\agsmi\Desktop\st114\homework6.py", line 61, in <module>
    x_final = square_root_for(a, a, max_iter, tol)

  File "C:\Users\agsmi\Desktop\st114\homework6.py", line 50, in square_root_for
    change = (abs(x[i] - x[i-1]) / x[i-1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Overall my question is, how do I fix this and have my first iteration return what the second returned, so that then there are only 7 iterations instead of 8.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove list() from for loop then test it.

```
for i in range(1,( max_iter + 1),1):
```

Also delete i = i+1 in your for loop.

and change the if statement:

```
if change > tol:
    x.append(1/2 * (x[i] + (a / x[i])))
    print('{}         | {:.14f} | {:.16f}'.format(i, x[i], change))
else:
    break
```

Comment: I just tried this, but it still returns the same output.

Comment: Did you delete i = i + 1?

Comment: yes I deleted it and removed list()

Answer (score 0):

```
# Problem 1.

def square_root_for(a, x0, max_iter = 10, tol=1e-14):  
    
    """ (number, integer, number) -> float

    Return an estimate of the square root of a number using the Heron's method.
        
    >>> square_root_for(5, 5)
    Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change
    -------------------------------------------------
    1         | 3.00000000000000 | 0.4000000000000000
    2         | 2.33333333333333 | 0.2222222222222222
    3         | 2.23809523809524 | 0.0408163265306123
    4         | 2.23606889564336 | 0.0009053870529653
    5         | 2.23606797749998 | 0.0000004106060359
    6         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000842
    7         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000000
    2.23606797749979
    """
    
    x = [x0]
    x.append(a/x0)
  
    print('Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change')
    print('-------------------------------------------------')
         
    
    for i in range(1,max_iter):
       #x[i+1] = (s1 + x[i]) / 2
        change = (abs(x[i] - x[i-1]) / x[i-1])
        if change > tol:
            x.append(1/2 * (x[i] + (a / x[i])))
        else:
            break
        print('{}         | {:.14f} | {:.16f}'.format(i, x[i], change))
    return(x[i])
# Don't change or delete the 5 lines of code below.
a = 5
max_iter = 100
tol = 1e-15
x_final = square_root_for(a, a, max_iter, tol)
print('Final estimate using square_root_for is {0}'.format(x_final))
```

I took out the i = i+1 line, simplified the range statement as mentioned by AAR, but the error you were getting was because it was looping and expecting to find an array value so you needed a break to escape from the for loop when the required precision is achieved.
edit - you also need to return a value x[i] from the function.

Output

```
Iteration | Estimate         | Relative Change
-------------------------------------------------
1         | 1.00000000000000 | 0.8000000000000000
2         | 3.00000000000000 | 2.0000000000000000
3         | 2.33333333333333 | 0.2222222222222222
4         | 2.23809523809524 | 0.0408163265306123
5         | 2.23606889564336 | 0.0009053870529653
6         | 2.23606797749998 | 0.0000004106060359
7         | 2.23606797749979 | 0.0000000000000842
Final estimate using square_root_for is 2.23606797749979
```

Comment: Earlier I marked this as solved but this is still incorrect, the output that is supposed to happen is shown in the docstring of my original question, could you help me further. For example, the first line is supposed to be 1         | 3.00000000000000 | 0.4000000000000000

Comment: I can give you a hint. You have 1 as your initial estimate. The output suggests using 5 as initial estimate. Maybe you should make the initial assignment outside the loop. Personally, I would add x0 as the first element of the list, calculate x1 outside the loop and then start looping.